# How to write pop(item) method for unsorted list

Tags: python, data-structures

I'm implementing some basic data structures in preparation for an exam and have come across the following issue. I want to implement an unsorted linked list, and have already implemented a `pop()` method, however I don't know, either syntactically or conceptually, how to make a function sometimes take an argument, sometimes not take an argument. I hope that makes sense.

```
def pop(self):
    current = self.head
    found = False
    endOfList = None

    while current != None and not found:
        if current.getNext() == None:
            found = True
            endOfList = current.getData()
            self.remove(endOfList)
            self.count = self.count - 1
        else:
            current = current.getNext()

    return endOfList
```

I want to know how to make the statement `unsortedList.pop(3)` valid, 3 being just an example and unsortedList being a new instance of the class.

Comment: How can your list be both unordered and linked? And if it is unordered, what does `.pop(3)` mean at all?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I'm guessing he means unsorted, not unordered? But yeah, that's definitely worth clarifying.

Comment: I think that by "unordered" @trainreq means "unsorted".

Comment: Sorry, I meant unsorted guys.

Comment: @trainreq "how to make a function sometimes take an argument, sometimes not take an argument. I hope that makes sense." No that doesn't make sense. In Python, a function can be with a parameter that takes a default argument when no argument is passed to the function, or an argument is passed to it. But there is no possibility, AFAIK, that a function could take sometimes no argument at all, and would take one in different circumstances.

Comment: @eyquem: The function always has a parameter, and from the function body's point of view it always receives an argument, but from the caller's point of view there is _not_ an argument. This is why the `*args` feature is described as "variable argument lists".

Comment: @eyquem: To clarify further: the caller's point of view is always the one that matters when you talk about arguments, because arguments are a feature of function call expressions. Which means the OP is asking for something completely reasonable.

Comment: @abarnert What I mean is: there are functions that takes no arguments, hence there is no ``defparameter`` written in the ``funcdef`` of the function body of their definitions. When such a function has no parameter  in its function body, it can't receive arguments "sometimes" : it NEVER receive arguments. There is no "sometimes"

Comment: @abarnert Well, what you say is correct: from the caller's point of view, sometimes an argument is passed to a function, and sometimes no argument is passed to the same function. And if one understand to TAKE as "to take what is passed to the function", then sometimes the function takes nothing and sometimes it receives something. What I understand personnally is the function with a default argument always takes something, either a passed external object, either the object (with its value) written as default argument. -

Comment: @abarnert And by the way , for me , an external object ISn't an argument, it is PASSED AS argument.

Comment: @eyquem: Yes, a function that has no parameters can't be called with no arguments sometimes and with other times. But a function that has only parameters with default values can be. Which is exactly what the OP asked for: "how to make a function sometimes take an argument, sometimes not take an argument". The answer is not "it's impossible", but "give it a parameter with a default value".

Comment: @abarnert CORRECTION Well, what you say is correct: from the caller's point of view, sometimes an argument is passed to a function, and sometimes no argument is passed to the same function, if this function has a default argument defined. And if one understand to TAKE as "to take what is passed to the function", then "sometimes the function takes nothing" means "sometimes it receives something". What I understand personnally is the function with a default argument always takes something, either a passed external object, either the object (with its value) written as default argument.

Comment: @abarnert I understand what you say. I agree with you, if considering that what is written by the OP must be understand as you say. What I think personnally is that it must be interpreted another way. But we are on this point at the great depth of the understanding of messages emited by persons. It is a too much incredibly complex field to be debated in the limited space of comments. Nor you nor me can have the absolute truth on this matter, because it depends of interpretation, we swim in relativity. - The other subject [continued]

Comment: @abarnert [continued] The other subject is far more important and out of relativity and subjectivity: what do the words 'parameter' and 'argument' mean in Python. It should be worrisome that all people wouldn't share the same understanding of these terms

Comment: @eyquem: I don't understand. You've agreed that what I say is correct in general, and then agreed that it applies here as long as you take "take" to mean "take", and yet you're still arguing against… I'm not sure what. The OP's question makes sense, everyone understood what he means, he uses the terms in the exact same way at least some of the Python docs did, and multiple people were able to give answers that were exactly what he was looking for. So, what's the problem?

Comment: @abarnert Yes, everyone understand what he means, because every one transforms in his/her brain the things to understand according to his/her mental patterns. What I think is that I am not sure the the questioner has a clear idea of what he expresses, and I'm not sure that the readers have a clear idea of what is in question in the OP's brain. I think that trying to catch the extreme subtleties of mental processes are like making a trip in a morass. That's why I don't think reasonable to debate of these things in comments, and personnally with my poor english.

Comment: @abarnert What I mean, in fact, is that "to TAKE" can be understood as "take what is passed to it, and if nothing is passed, it takes nothing from outside!" OR as "take what it MUST take, and if nothing is passed from the outside of the function, it takes the object defined as default argument". According what a brain understand, the consequences will be different. But let drop this, it's too much complicated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic syntax (and a common use case) for using a parameter with a default value looks like this:

```
def pop(self, index=None):
    if index is not None:
        #Do whatever your default behaviour should be
```

You then just have to identify how you want your behaviour to change based on the argument. I am just guessing that the argument should specify the index of the element that should be pop'ed from the list.

If that is the case you can directly use a valid default value instead of `None` e.g. `0`

```
def pop(self, index=0):
```

Comment: It is not a default parameter, it is a parameter that takes a default argument

Comment: Thanks, I adjusted the description.

Comment: @eyquem: No, it's not, it's a parameter with a default value. There's no such thing as default arguments. His original phrasing (and mine) was a bit sloppy, but your correction is just as sloppy. See my answer for full details.

Comment: @abarnert Well, I'm not alright. When ``f(p = thing)`` is written in a code, I see it as follows: the parameter ``p`` takes the argument ``thing``, and the parameter ``p`` is assigned to the object **thing**. After the assignement , we can speak of the object **p**. - When I write ``p`` and ``thing``, I mean the names == identifiers that are written in the code. When I write **p** and **thing**, I want to indicate the objects whose names are ``p`` and ``thing``.

Comment: @eyquem: The official documentation disagrees with you. The "argument" is the thing in the call expression; the "parameter value" is the thing that the function receives. So, if you call `f()`, there is no argument, and `f` receives the value `thing` because there is no argument value. Meanwhile, I'm not sure what the tangent about assignment is, but `f(p = thing)` is not actually doing a real assignment; it's binding a default value cell/slot/attribute in the function object.

Comment: @abarnert "Every object has an identity, a type and a value." (http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types) For me it's even not well expressed in the doc. For me, an object has a type and a value, that is to say there is two components of an object, its type and its value. And I don't think that its identity is a component of the object. But, sure, the object lies somewhere in the memory and when ``id()`` is applied to the object , it gives a number representing its location in memory, so we can roughly say that it ""has" this identity

Comment: @abarnert What I want to point out is that when we write ``p = thing`` in a code, that means that the object was name is ``thing``, which I indicate by **thing**, is assigned to the identifier ``p``. ANd so, it is not the value of **thing** that is assigned, it IS the object **thing**

Comment: @abarnert I deem that the documentation isn't well written in all its parts, I mean that there must have been several different writers on my opinion, and the ways of expressions are not homogeneous throughout the doc.

Comment: @eyquem: Yes, the technical term "parameter value" is a little confusing, because really there's a "parameter value and type", and the docs are never very consistent about to what extent a type is an inherent property of a value. But that doesn't mean you should call a parameter value an "argument" (and not have anything left to call an argument).

Comment: @abarnert I wrote this 'the documentation isn't well written in all its parts' above because there's the following sentence "This is especially important to understand when a default parameter is a mutable object," in the doc (http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions)

Comment: @abarnert In the doc, we read ``defparameter ::= parameter ["=" expression]`` . The parameter is on the left

Comment: @eyquem: Your argument was that "default parameter" is incorrect, and "parameter with default argument" is correct. Now you're arguing that "default parameter" is actually mentioned in the docs, and implied elsewhere in the docs. Which seems to prove the exact opposite of what you intended. But the reality is exactly what I said: "default parameter" is shorthand, not quite accurate, but frequently used anyway (apparently even in the docs). Likewise, using "argument" when you mean either "(formal) parameter" or "parameter value" is not accurate, but frequently used anyway.

Comment: @abarnert In (http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types) there is the sentence ``It should be called with an argument list containing the same number of items as the function’s formal parameter list.`` The one who wrote this had a clear idea of the things, in my opinion. This sentence washes all ambiguity: the parameters are what receive, the arguments are what is passed. He uses the term "formal parameter" to make clear that he speaks about the parameters that receive, because he knows some persons make confusion and call parameter what is in fact argument.

Comment: @eyquem: If that were the literal definition, interpreted the way you prefer, it would mean that you can't legally call `*args` or `**kwargs` functions, which would make them pretty useless, which implies that you're misinterpreting things. I believe in this paragraph it's referring to what should be delivered to the function code, not what should be passed in the call expression. The fact that it talks about the "argument list" instead of the "arguments" backs that up. But really, no matter what the _right_ interpretation is, your interpretation doesn't work.

Comment: @abarnert Try to read the above sentence replacing 'argument' with 'receiver' and 'parameter' with 'what is passed'. It gives ``It should be called with a receiver list containing the same number of items as the function's s list of what is passed.`` It makes no sense, the list of receivers has not to adapt oneself to the number of what is passed. Except, precisely, if ``*args`` or ``**kwargs`` are eplicitly written

Comment: @eyquem: Now you're just inventing new definitions for things. Yes, the sentence makes no sense with 'receiver', because arguments are not receivers in any reasonable sense of the word. What does that prove, or even imply? (Some languages—mostly in the Smalltalk family tree—do refer to the object a method is called on as the 'receiver', and in that sense, the receiver could be considered the first argument in a Python method call, but that still doesn't help me understand what you're trying to say.)

Comment: @abarnert ``function**'s** formal parameter list`` Isn't it clear for you that the formal parameter list **BELONGS** to the function ? What will be passed later isn't concerned here.

Comment: @abarnert I'm not inventing definitions, I tried to unravel the confusion in which things are expressed by people who didn't express well, even in the official docs. - I ask you again: what the hell does it mean ``defparameter ::= parameter ["=" expression]`` if it doesn't mean that the parameter is on the left ? This manner of expressing the formal definitions has been invented to make the things clear. Will you pretend that this isn't clear ?

Comment: @eyquem: Of course, the formal parameter list belongs to the function. Parameters are the things the function definition statement has. Arguments are the things the function call expression has. Parameter values are the things the function body receives when the function call is executed. A `defparameter` is part of a formal parameter list, and it's defined as a `parameter` plus an optional default value specified by `= expression`. So, the way to write a function that sometimes takes an argument and sometimes does not is to give it one `defparameter` with a default value.

Comment: @abarnert In ``def g(x)`` ,is ``x`` a parameter for you ? In ``def f(y, p = 45)`` , is ``p`` a parameter for you ?

Comment: @abarnert I regret but there is a conflict between what I understand by 'parameter' and what you do. For me a parameter is ONLY the name == identifier choosen to be written in the function definition's body: it is composed of letters, underscore and numbers, and that's all. A parameter is assigned to the object it receives. People imply by 'parameter' the object after it has been assigned, but not me.

Comment: @eyquem: Yes, `x`, `y`, and `p` are parameters here, just as you say. And when I then write `f(1) + f(2, 3)`, the arguments are `1` in the first call, `2` and `3` in the second call. And the values received by `f`'s code are `1` and `45` in the first call, `2` and `3` in the second call. Therefore, `f` is a function with two parameters, that sometimes takes one argument, sometimes two.

Comment: @abarnert Well, all is well then ? I was thinking you pretended that x,y,p were arguments and the objects 1,2,45 parameters values.Personally, I prefer to say that object **1**,**2**,**45**,**3** are passed AS arguments , but they are not argument, they continue to live in outside of the function if they were. But that's a minor point

Comment: @eyquem: Yes, the one point of contention is whether `45` is an argument. We both agree that `p` is the parameter in the definition of `f`, and `45` is the parameter value in the execution of `f`'s body, and the docs are reasonably but not 100% consistent on that. But the question is whether, in the function call `f(1)`, the arguments are just `1` or `1` and `45`. I think the latter is untenable, especially when you deal with more complex cases (`*args`, mutable defaults, objects with `__call__`, …), and also leaves us without a term to name the things the docs name arguments.

Comment: @abarnert Oh I see now. For you, an argument is what is passed to a function from the outside to the inside, it's a point of view from the outside. For me, an argument is what is received by the parameters of a function, from the outside or from a default argument. It's a point of view from the inside, since, as soon as a parameter is defined for a function, it must belongs to the local namespace of the function with its assigned object after the function has been called.

Comment: @abarnert  The name says it all: default **argument**, I don't do a new definition, I accept what is said to me by official expression: default arguments are arguments.....

Comment: @abarnert I don't see what is untenable and the difficulty with *args, ``__call__`` ....

Comment: @eyquem: There's only so much that can be explained in these comments, especially if you want me to start getting into what would have to happen inside any reasonable interpreter to make various complex function calls work, so I'm going to stop here unless you really, really want to continue.

Comment: @abarnert Oh yes, you are right, we must stop. Python is too vast to speak about it in comments. And here it is very late. Thank you. Maybe you will explain one day in the future what you imply with your remark. Bye

Answer (score 1):

First, add a parameter with a default value to the function:

```
def pop(self, item=None):
```

Now, in the code, `if item is None:`, you can do the "no param" thing; otherwise, use `item`. Whether you want to switch at the top, or lower down in the logic, depends on your logic. In this case, `item is None` probably means "match the first item", so you probably want a single loop that checks `item is None or current.data == item:`.

Sometimes you'll want to do this for a parameter that can legitimately be `None`, in which case you need to pick a different sentinel. There are a few questions around here (and blog posts elsewhere) on the pros and cons of different choices. But here's one way:

```
class LinkedList(object):
    _sentinel = object()
    def pop(self, item=_sentinel):
```

Unless it's valid for someone to use the private `_sentinel` class member of LinkedList as a list item, this works. (If that *is* valid—e.g., because you're building a debugger out of these things—you have to get even trickier.)

The terminology on this is a bit tricky. Quoting the docs:

> When one or more top-level parameters have the form `parameter = expression`, the function is said to have “default parameter values.”

To understand this: "Parameters" (or "formal parameters") are the things the function is defined to take; "arguments" are things passed to the function in a call expression; "parameter values" (or "actual parameters", but this just makes things more confusing) are the values the function body receives. So, it's technically incorrect to refer to either "default parameters" or "parameters with default arguments", but both are quite common, because even experts find this stuff confusing. (If you're curious, or just not confused yet, see [function definitions](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) and [calls](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#calls) in the reference documentation for full details.)

Comment: It is not a default parameter, it is a parameter that takes a default argument

Comment: @eyquem: No, it's a default-valued parameter. People understand the shortcut term "default parameter", and "parameter that takes a default argument", even though they're both wrong. But you're right, it's a bad idea to give people bad terminological habits when they're first learning something, so I've added the details.

Answer (score 0):

Is your exam using Python specifically? If not, you may want to look into [function overloading.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading) Python doesn't support this feature, but many other languages do, and is a very common approach to solving this kind of problem.

In Python, you can get a lot of mileage out of using parameters with default values (as Michael Mauderer's example points out).

Comment: Well, given that the implementation would be identical in this case (save for setting the default value), one wouldn't use an overload, or only to delegate to the other overload with the default value (which is basically *emulating* default values).

Comment: Although I have my answer already, why is function overloading not supported by Python? I am familiar with the concept, though I had no idea it wasn't supported in Python.

Comment: @delnan- I agree with you concerning this specific example. However, since the poster mentioned that this was prep for an exam, it seemed worthwhile to point out that Python's approach isn't the only way this is done.

Comment: @trainreq Overloading, the way it's usually done, requires static typing and early binding (Python has neither). There are other, somewhat similar dispatch schemes (e.g. multimethods), but they are significantly less popular, and can easily add a significant overhead for function calls. That, and I guess Guido didn't like the idea. Turns out it's rarely needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
def pop(self, index=None):
    prev = None
    current = self.head
    if current is None:
       raise IndexError("can't pop from empty list")
    if index is None:
       index = 0 # the first item by default (counting from head)

    if index < 0:
       index += self.count
    if not (0 <= index < self.count):
       raise IndexError("index out of range")

    i = 0
    while i != index:
        i += 1
        prev = current
        current = current.getNext()
        assert current is not None # never happens if list is self-consistent

    assert i == index
    value = current.getData()
    self.remove(current, prev)
    ##self.count -= 1 # this should be in self.remove()
    return value
```